# creation vs updation of keys in redis

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-py

I have a very simple doubt. I was reading up on redis and I didn't get the answer for this question.

Consider you already have created a key that is a `list`. After sometime, I need to replace the contents of the `list` with new content. 
I can keep a timeout on the `list` key and create the same name key for the modified `list` or I can reuse the originally created key for the `list`.

So which approach is better? Creating new keys or updating the existing keys?

Comment: how do you "update the existing keys"?

Comment: By setting it to zero if it's an integer or setting it `[]` if it's a list

Comment: Redis' Lists can't be empty - to replace it, just `DEL` and re-create. The same goes for String keys. FYI - empty keys (e.g. a List without members) are automatically deleted by Redis.

Comment: Ohk got it..thank you @ItamarHaber